# Is it possible to have prophecy and visions from the sitra achra?

Tags: rabbis, chabad, nevua-prophecy, navi-prophets, eliyahu-hanavi

BH

Is it possible the that the vision the person is receiving coming from a source of impurity or sitra achra or is this just called sitra achra and yetzer hara? Like are there levels to this that is keneged the side of kedusha?

Comment: shemuel 1:19:24

Answer (score 2):

There are indeed impure forces that Hashem created specifically for the sake of false prophecy, when it is decreed upon a person. For example, the maaseh in [Kings 1:22](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Kings.22.20?ven=The_Koren_Jerusalem_Bible&lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=he) where נָבוֹת*, the lying spirit, volunteers to provide a false prophecy for the sake of tricking Achav into going to a war to his death.

See [Derech Hashem 3:4:10-11](https://www.sefaria.org/Derekh_HaShem%2C_Part_Three%2C_On_the_Prophetic_Experience.10?lang=bi&with=Navigation&lang2=en) for more details on false and impure prophecy and its various facets and rules.

<sup>* See [Sanhedrin 89a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.89a.15?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he)</sup>